# write the folder path for it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code below. Please help me write the "input" and "output" folder paths for it.
For example:

```
"input": C: \ Users \ Name \ Desktop \ Input \ *. Txt

"output": C: \ Users \ Name \ Desktop \ Output \ * .txt (it creates new txt)
```

The txt file name in the input holds the output.

And from a folder of many txt files it removes "%" and exports it to another folder

```
   f1 = open('trang.txt', 'r')
   f2 = open('trang2.txt', 'w')
   for line in f1:
       f2.write(line.replace('%', ''))
   f1.close()
   f2.close()
```

I use python 3.6.2

Comment: **@Monso**, your question is unclear. Please add more explanation. Why you are reading **trang.txt** and writing to **trang2.txt** etc. Give more inputs and expected outputs. Do you want to copy all the files available in **Input** directory to **Output** directory?

Comment: when i run it, trang.txt it creates trang2.txt and trang2.txt will be deleted %

Comment: Can you help me write "input" and "output" paths for it and in "input" are multiple txt files. and in turn edit each file and export to a new folder @RishikeshAgrawani

Comment: What the contents inside **trang.txt**? Why do you want to replace `%` with `''`? What's your original intention to write program? Why do you want to delete **trang2.txt**?

Comment: Yea, I will help you, that's why I am asking for the inputs.

Comment: I want in an "input" folder with lots of txt files and replace "%" with "" and that replacement file creates a new txt file in the "output" folder. @RishikeshAgrawani

Comment: As I understand from your comment, **Input** folder has multiple text files and you want to copy all these files to **Output** folder. But why do you want to replace `%` and where it exists? Please clear it.

Comment: right . And of course in the output txt file has the character "%" replaced by "".

Comment: Okay, the line inside text files in **Input** folder contains `%` and you want to replace it with `''`? Am I correct? It means the **Output** folder is going to contain the text files with lines that has no `%` in it. Thanks.

Comment: I want to delete "%" in txt. Since I'm using ffmpeg when there is "%" in txt, it's not working. Since there are so many txt files I have to use python

Comment: Okay let me write code and get back to you with new comment. You check and suggest me for correction if it doesn't satisfy your problem. Thanks.

Comment: ok i will wait you. Thank you very much

Comment: **@Monso**, I'm done with writing the code and answered it. Please check it if it works and please let me know if you face any problem. You have to replace the value of 2 variables inside try block of my code. These variables are **input_dir** and **output_dir**. Please check it.

Comment: It works very well. I really thank you very much. You explain very clearly. Really thank you

Comment: No problem **@Monso**. Enjoy Python. Good luck.

Comment: You have free time. Please help me write one more code. thanks you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Monso**, as per your provided inputs, expected outputs in problem & in comments, I've written the code to solve your problem.

In my case:

- Input directory: `C:\Users\pc-user\Desktop\Input`
- Output directory: `C:\Users\pc-user\Desktop\Output`

And I have 3 file `A.txt`, `B.txt` & `C.txt` inside **Input** directory with contents as follows.

> You've to use your own paths as you've mentioned in problem.

#### » `C:\\Users\\pc-user\\Desktop\\Input\\A.txt`

```
This is %nice day%.
Program %20 files %
```

[image]

#### » `C:\\Users\\pc-user\\Desktop\\Input\\B.txt`

```
This is my nice journey with % Rishikesh. Monso is % also %% here.

Monso %%%% is solving the Python problems % at % mor%ning.
```

[image]

#### » `C:\\Users\\pc-user\\Desktop\\Input\\C.txt`

```
This is % book.
This i%s i%%s a % boy%.
I kno%w P%y%t%%ho%n. %
```

[image]

> Copy the below code, replace the value of **input_dir** and **output_dir** variables with your own paths and run.

#### » `Python code`

```
import glob 
import os 

def copy_files_to_output(input_dir, output_dir):
    # Creating a regex path for all text files inside Input directory
    input_dir_regex_path = os.path.join(input_dir, "*.txt");

    # Getting list of absolute paths of all the text files inside Input directory
    input_files_paths = glob.glob(input_dir_regex_path);

    # Iterating over a list of input file names
    for full_path in input_files_paths:
        # Get text file name from absolute path
        file_name = full_path.split('\\')[-1]

        # Reading input text file 
        # (Open file in read mode, 'r' is default here; the 2nd default parameter to open())
        # You do not need to close file (if you open as follows using with statement)
        with open(full_path) as in_file:
            # Creating full path name of output text file
            output_file_path = output_dir + "\\" + file_name;

            # Create a new file inside Output directory
            # 'w' specifies to open file in write mode
            with open(output_file_path, 'w') as out_file:
                # Get list of lines in text file
                all_lines = in_file.readlines();

                # Write all lines to a new file (inside Output directory)
                for line in all_lines:
                    # Replace all '%' characters present in line with '' 
                    line = line.replace('%', '');
                    out_file.write(line);


# Starting point
if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    try:
        # Code to be executed
        input_dir = "C:\\Users\\pc-user\\Desktop\\Input"; # Use your own path
        output_dir = "C:\\Users\\pc-user\\Desktop\\Output"; # Use your own path

        # Call copy_files_to_output() function
        copy_files_to_output(input_dir, output_dir);

        # Operation successful
        print("Copy operation successful");
    except Exception as error:
        # Code to be executed if any Exception occurs
        print("Exception occurred", error);
```

Once the above code executes successfully, it will write all text files present inside **input_dir** to **output_dir**. In my case, the contents inside **Output** directory looks like as mentioned below:

#### » `C:\\Users\\pc-user\\Desktop\\Output\\A.txt`

```
This is nice day.
Program 20 files
```

[image]

#### » `C:\\Users\\pc-user\\Desktop\\Output\\B.txt`

```
This is my nice journey with  Rishikesh. Monso is  also  here.

Monso  is solving the Python problems  at  morning.
```

[image]

#### » `C:\\Users\\pc-user\\Desktop\\Output\\C.txt`

```
This is  book.
This is is a  boy.
I know Python.
```

[image]

Comment: It works very well. I really thank you very much. You explain very clearly. Really thank you

Comment: No problem **@Monso**. Good luck.

Comment: You have free time. Please help me write one more code. thanks you very much

Comment: Yea, of coarse. Just tell me how can I help you? Brief your problem.

Comment: Ibox facebook " Tuấn Hồ "

Comment: I sent you a message. Please agree to go